# Best and safest way of displaying the results submitted by a wysiwyg form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, wysiwyg

I just implemented http://xing.github.com/wysihtml5/ in my `Post` model's form:

**_form.html.erb:**

```
 <div class="field">
    <%= render 'shared/toolbar' %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, id: "wysihtml5-textarea", placeHolder: "Content" %>
  </div>
```

**show.html.erb:**

```
  <span class="post-content">
    <%= @post.content %>
  </span>
```

What's the best and safest way of displaying results of the wysiwyg editor?

(Right now the output looks like this):

```
text <i>editor</i> <b>test</b>&nbsp;text <u>editor</u> test&nbsp;text editor test
```

(Not sure if I need too much security, since it only have the `<i><b><u>` tags. In that case, should I just use `raw` or `escape`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful to HTML insertion! Take a look to the [sanitize gem](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize)

And of course, use raw to display your sanitized html:

`<%= raw @post.content %>`

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this:

```
<%= raw @post.content %>
```

But do you trust your users? Since they can also insert HTML (as I see from the demo) I'd say not to.